# Incorrect Syntax Near GO in ADODB Connection for Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I'm trying to pull data from a SQLServer database with a stored proc directly into and excel spreadsheet. I'm trying to make a dashboard that will allow the user to make a selection for the specific month they want to see and pull the data for that month. Once the data is pulled, the dashboard will automatically calculate which charts the user will see and so forth.  This is my first time pulling from an ADODB connection, though, and I'm getting a problem  trying to actually pull the data. I get the error "Incorrect Syntax Near 'GO'" on the line where I'm trying to copy from the recordset. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This is the new code. I'm now getting the run-time error 3704: Cannot perform this operation when the object is closed. It's still happening when I try to copy from the recordset.

```
Sub btnPullData_Click()
Dim objConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rngTableCell As Range
Dim drpPicker As DropDown
Dim strDropVal As String
Dim objCommand As New ADODB.Command


Set rngTableCell = Range("celFirstInTable")
rngTableCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete

Set drpPicker = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").DropDowns("dropFis_Month")
strDropVal = Format(drpPicker.List(drpPicker.ListIndex), "mmm-yy")

objConn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=KPITRACKER;Data Source=JEFFSQL"

With objCommand
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "DynamicPhonesSP"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@TimeSum", advarWChar, , 1, "m")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@TimeSum1", advarWChar, , 1, "d")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@TimeParam", advarWChar, , 20, strDropVal)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@RptLevel", adInteger, , , 1)
    .ActiveConnection = objConn
    Set objRecordset = .Execute
End With

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("B6").CopyFromRecordset objRecordset

objRecordset.Close
Set objRecordset = Nothing
objConn.Close
Set objConn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: GO is more of a hint for ssms rather than part of t-sql, remove it

Comment: Does the stored procedure actually return a recordset? If you execute it in SSMS, do you get a grid?

Comment: Yes, I do. I get a grid with all the stats for whichever month I put into the @timeparam parameter.

Comment: @user2970747 Can you use SQL Profiler to see the generated SQL when using the VBA code? Also, what is the definition of your stored procedure? (just the data types of the parameters will do).

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to use Profiler...The data types are as follows:`@TimeSum - char(1), @TimeSum1-char(1), @TimeParam - varchar(10), @RptLevel  - int` When I run it from SSMS, it has "N" in front of the string params. Would that have anything to do with it?

Comment: @user2970747 I've updated the answer to match those datatypes. Note if you prefix your comments with `@Laurence` I get a notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call stored procedures more directly: (probably some syntax issues)

```vb
Sub btnPullData_Click()
    Dim lCon as New ADODB.Connection
    Dim lCommand as New ADODB.Command
    Dim lRecordset as ADODB.Recordset
    Dim lR As Range
    Dim lMonth as Variant

    Set lR = Range("celFirstInTable")
    lR.ListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete

    lCon.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=KPITRACKER;Data Source=server"
    lMonth = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Shapes("dropFis_Month").ControlFormat.Value

    With lCommand
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "DynamicPhonesSP"
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@TimeSum", adChar, , 1, "m")
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@TimeSum1", adChar, , 1, "d")
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@TimeParam", advarChar, , 10, lMonth)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@RptLevel", adInteger, , , 1)
        .ActiveConnection = lCon
        Set lRecordset = .Execute
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("B6").CopyFromRecordset lRecordset

    lRecordset.Close
    lCon.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: That definitely worked better. Now, though, it's giving me  run-time error: "3704 Operation is not allowed when the object is closed" at the same point. Did it close the connection on its own? I made sure to close after everything else was done, but can it do it itself?

Comment: @user2970747 I'd misspelt `ActiveConnection` if that's not the problem, add what you have now to the question, and say which line it's failing on.